# List object as class field

Tags: java

I want to set `List` object as a class field and then use `ArrayList()` as a concrete class of `List`. 
The reason is that I want to call `setData` method many times in different parts of program and every time it must add data to the same object data, not different ones.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class container {
    private static List<String> data = ArrayList<String>();

    public static List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public static void setData(String a) {
        data.add(a);
    }
}
```

I guess this code should cause error.
How can I change the code so that it has the similar result with correct syntax?

If this code will not cause errors can anyone tell me when(at what part of execution program) will be static data object created?
P.S. I am not going to create container object,just want to call container.setData(String a) method many times in program.

Comment: Why do you think there'll be an error?

Comment: Add a type specifier to ArrayList: new ArrayList<String>()

Comment: Indeed - it's simple for you to *try* this, and then include the specific error in your question, if indeed you get one.

Comment: And why `static`. Sometimes i wish every programmer had to pay $1 for charity when misusing `static`.

Comment: this will compile in java 1.7, which version you will be using?

Comment: what is the problem in this code? only thing in generic type is missed out in ArrayList

Comment: Maroun Maroun,because I think this will create different objects of "data" every time i call "setData".

Comment: @NikaTsogiaidze Then it's *not* a syntax error...

Comment: Hmmm ... Even in this short code snippet, I see four problems! 1) Missing type argument in ArrayList instantiation. 2) Class "container" should be named "Container" (capital C). See code conventions. 3) Field and methods are static. Arrrgh. 4) The worst one: The method "setData" doesn't actually set something. It _adds_ a value to the internal data structure. It really should be named "addData".

Comment: `new` word is missing here `private static List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if you add the missing `new` word and it will work as you want. The ArrayList will be instantiated when the `container` class is loaded. This usually happens when the control flow reaches a class that references this class. So whenever you call any of these methods the data field will already be ready.

However you may want to learn the '[singleton design pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=singleton%20design%20pattern%20in%20java)' and you may want to synchronize the access to the shared object if you [create several threads](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20threading) (or you use a library that do that for you).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class container {
    private static List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(); // <-- new was missing

    public static List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public static void setData(String a) {
        data.add(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class container {
private static List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
//              for java 1.5-1.6 point type here ^^^^^^^ 
//              for java 1.7+ you can use new ArrayList<>();
public static List<String> getData() { return data;}
public static void setData(String a) { data.add(a);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cite: "The reason is that I want to call setData method many times in different parts of program and every time it must add data to the same object data, not different ones."

If your data field is declared as `static`, there will only be one data field, so this should not pose any problems. Have you tested the code, or do you just *think* there will be errors?

Comment: Thank you.First useful answer.  No I have not tested the code,I thought that it would cause logical error and check this error would take too much time,just therefore I asked here in order to understand opinion of experienced coders.